# Program is ignoring .cpp file and refuses to acknowledge Ship.cpp file. Keeps saying "this file does not belong to any project target"

Tags: c++, project, target

My problem is that for some reason main.cpp refuses to acknowledge that Ship.cpp exists. If I add in main.cpp #include "Ship.cpp", the code works with no problems. What could be the problem? (IDE is CLion). It has never happened before.

When I open ship.cpp, on top it says "this file does not belong to any project target".

Has anyone ever encountered such problem and what is the way to fix it?

SHIP.CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"

std::string Ship::GetName() {
    return this->name;
}

int Ship::GetStorage() {
    return this->storage;
}

void Ship::SetName(std::string name) { this->name = name; }

void Ship::SetStorage(int storage) { this->storage = storage; }

void Ship::setAll(std::string name, int storage) {
    this->name = name;
    this->storage = storage;
}

Ship::Ship(std::string name, int storage) {
    this->name = name;
    this->storage = storage;
}

Ship::Ship() {
    this->name = "Stock Ship";
    this->storage = 10;
}

void Ship::toString() {
    std::cout << "This ship is called " <<
              this->name << " and has the storage capacity of " <<
              this->storage << " units.";
}
```

Ship.h:

```
    #ifndef UOSTASGAME_SHIP_H
#define UOSTASGAME_SHIP_H

#include <string>

class Ship {

private:


    std::string name;
    int storage;

public:

    Ship();
    Ship(std::string, int);

    std::string GetName();
    void SetName(std::string name);

    int GetStorage();
    void SetStorage(int storage);

    void setAll(std::string, int);

    void toString();

};


#endif //UOSTASGAME_SHIP_H
```

Main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
int main() {

    Ship ship("Becky",10);
    Ship a;

    ship.toString();
    a.toString();



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLion uses CMake to organize and build your project, one of your project files should be `CMakeLists.txt`, and inside it, there should be a line that looks like that

```
add_executable(target_name Main.cpp)
```

You need to add your Ship.cpp file to sources there

```
add_executable(target_name Main.cpp Ship.cpp)
```

As a side note, you probably added the Ship.cpp file manually, through console or file explorer, if you add it through your IDE, by right-clicking the project root in the left panel and choose add new class, CLion will add the sources to CMakeLists.txt automatically.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! The problem has been solved, however - I did add them like intended trough new class. Bizarre!

Comment: If I remember correctly, when adding a new class through IDE there's a little check-box if and where the files should be added from CMake, maybe you checked it off by mistake.

Comment: @JeronimasKlevinskas _The problem has been solved_ So, please, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (And, once, you are in the help pages, you could take the [tour] as well, as you didn't yet.)